# Use unicode font for cyrillic in gnuplot

Tags: unicode, gnuplot, cyrillic, eps

Why I need to do this? I'n writting my diploma in laTeX and almost finish them, but I want to use in graph labels and legend the same font that LateX uses.

As I know, the default LaTeX font in CM, so I opened example font from /usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/public/cm-super and /usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/public/cm-unicode in font viewer and expect that they support cyrillic.

Next, according to http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_4.0/fontfile.html, I changed my gnuplot script:

```
set encoding utf8
set terminal postscript eps enhanced size 8in,5.4in fontfile "./sfci0900.pfb" "SFCI0900" 30

set output "./graph_new_font.eps"

set xlabel "{/SFCI0900 z/L_d}"
set xrange [0:0.1]
set ylabel "{/SFCI0900 Пиковая интенсивность}"
set yrange [0:10]
```

I view the produced EPS with Evince, but only "z/L_d" font have changed, but ylabel is empty. :( IDIW?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be a bit of overkill, but it is the only way I can think of that might be able to accomplish what you want:

```
set terminal fig metric textspecial color;
set output "./graph_new_font.fig"
```

That will output the `gnuplot` image to an [`xfig`](http://www.xfig.org/) image.  Next, you can use the [`fig2tikz`](http://kogs-www.informatik.uni-hamburg.de/~meine/software/figpy/#fig2tikz) script to conver the `.fig` file into a [TikZ](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pgf/) image:

```
fig2tikz ./graph_new_font.fig > ./graph_new_font.tikz
```

Finally, you can then insert that image into your LaTeX document:

```
\input{graph_new_font.tikz}
```

(make sure to `\usepackage{tikz}` in your preamble, of course).

Using this method, *all* of the text in your `gnuplot` image will be rendered by LaTeX itself; no need to mess with fonts.  In the `gnuplot` file, just type the labels and legends as if you were writing them in LaTeX.

Comment: Thanks. As I understand, this also applies to epslatex or pdf terminal.

Comment: Correct.  Using the `fig` terminal was ultimately to get the graph into TikZ format, the benefit of which is that it would all be rendered in LaTeX (including the text).  Удачи!