# TikZ + gnuplot on a Mac

Tags: tikz-pgf, mac, gnuplot

I'm using LaTeX a lot in my work and I switched to Mac recently. I installed TeX Live and everything works fine, except for plotting a figure with gnuplot.

I installed gnuplot 4.4.3 first simply in the Terminal as I read in the internet, but didn't work, then after surfing I installed Fink and Macports and gnuplot again through Macports. I know it's a mess, but the error message hasn't changed, it has remained the same, which is the following:

```
gnuplot> set table "proba.f0.table"; set format "%.5f"
             ^
         "proba.f0.gnuplot", line 1: valid set options:  [] = choose one, {} means optional

    'angles', 'arrow', 'autoscale', 'bars', 'border', 'boxwidth',
    'clabel', 'clip', 'cntrparam', 'colorbox', 'contour', 'decimalsign',
    'dgrid3d', 'dummy', 'encoding', 'fit', 'format', 'grid',
    'hidden3d', 'historysize', 'isosamples', 'key', 'label', 'locale',
    'logscale', '[blrt]margin', 'mapping', 'mouse', 'multiplot',
    'offsets', 'origin', 'output', 'palette', 'parametric', 'pm3d',
    'pointsize', 'polar', 'print', '[rtuv]range', 'samples', 'size',
    'style', 'surface', 'terminal', tics', 'ticscale', 'ticslevel',
    'timestamp', 'timefmt', 'title', 'view', '[xyz]{2}data',
    '[xyz]{2}label', '[xyz]{2}range', '{no}{m}[xyz]{2}tics',
    '[xyz]{2}[md]tics', '{[xyz]{2}}zeroaxis', 'zero'



Package pgf Warning: Plot data file `proba.f0.table' not found. on input line 4
6.
```

The Latex code is the following:

```
\documentclass[trans]{beamer}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newenvironment{stepenumerate}{\begin{enumerate}[<+->]}{\end{enumerate}}
\newenvironment{stepitemize}{\begin{itemize}[<+->]}{\end{itemize} }
\newenvironment{stepenumeratewithalert}{\begin{enumerate}[<+-| alert@+>]}{\end{enumerate}}
\newenvironment{stepitemizewithalert}{\begin{itemize}[<+-| alert@+>]}{\end{itemize} }
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
%\useoutertheme[footline=authortitle]{miniframes}
%\setbeamercovered{still covered={\opaqueness<1->{25}}} 
\setbeamercovered{invisible}
\usefonttheme{structurebold}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{P.d.f. with different degrees of freedom}

  \begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[y=5cm]
    \draw[domain=0:4,thick,color=orange] plot[id=f0,samples=100] 
       function{0.5*(gamma(3)/(gamma(1)*gamma(2)))*1/((1+0.5*x)**3)} node at (1,0.8) {$\scriptstyle n=2\textsf{,}\; m=4$};

    \draw (0,0) node[below left] {$0$};
    \draw (3.5,1) node[above] {$\scriptstyle f\left(x;n,m\right)=\left(\frac{n}{m}\right)^{\frac{n}{2}}\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{n+m}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{m}{2}\right)}\frac{x^{\frac{n}{2}-1}}{\left(1+\frac{n}{m}x\right)^{\frac{n+m}{2}}}$};

    \draw[->,semithick] (-0.2,0) -- (4.2,0) node[right] {$x$};
    \draw[->,semithick] (0,-0.05) -- (0,1.2) node[left] {$f\left(x\right)$};

    \foreach \x in {1,2,...,4}
      \draw (\x,2pt) -- (\x,-2pt) node[below] {\x};
    \foreach \y in {0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1}
      \draw (2pt,\y) -- (-2pt,\y) node[left] {\y};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{center}

  \transwipe
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

What can the problem be? I'm unable to solve it, but I'd like to use gnuplot on my Mac.

---

#### Edit 1 (moved here from an answer by a moderator)

Thanks a lot for the quick replies. I'm sorry, but I didn't clarify a couple of issues.

1. I'm using TexShop and it works fine.
2. `--shell-escape` is configured, and also `-enable-write18`
3. gnuplot works, although I think I installed it twice... When in Terminal I write `gnuplot`, it starts gnuplot 4.4 with patchlevel 3, but when I write `/usr/local/bin/gnuplot`, it starts gnuplot 4.0 with patchlevel 0. The first set aquaterm (which is installed) and doesn't plot, and the second X11 (also installed) which works well. Can this be the problem? Which one should I keep and how to uninstall the other?
4. Placing `& -shell-escape`at the beginning of the document results in an error message: `Misplaced alignment tab character &`
5. Since gnuplot doesn't work, I use now pgfplot which is also great, but gnuplot is more flexible and I can represent more functions with it.
6. Some recommended on other sites to change the **pgfmoduleplot.code.tex** file and change the line

   ```
   \xdef\pgf@gnuplot@head#1{set terminal table; set output “#1.table”; set format “%.5f”}
   ```

   to

   ```
   \xdef\pgf@gnuplot@head#1{set table; set output “#1.table”; set format “%.5f”}
   ```

   However, I have no such a line, but have

   ```
    \xdef\pgf@gnuplot@head{set table \noexpand\pgf@plottablefile@quoted; set format "%.5f"}
   ```

---

#### Edit 2 (moved here from an answer by a moderator)

I think I found out where the problem lies. As I wrote before, I have two gnuplots installed. When in Terminal I write gnuplot, it starts gnuplot 4.4 with patchlevel 3, but when I write /usr/local/bin/gnuplot, it starts gnuplot 4.0 with patchlevel 0.

I tried to create the gnuplot table in the terminal by `gnuplot proba.f0.gnuplot` and it worked well and then TexShop could make the job. However, when i tried with the other version and wrote `/usr/local/bin/gnuplot proba.f0.gnuplot` it gave me the familiar error message.

So the problem must be with version 4.0. How can I uninstall it from /usr/local/bin and put the other one there?

#### Edit 3

@Altermundus: Thanks a lot, I was able to uninstall gnuplot from `/usr/local/bin`. Now the only thing I have to do is to make Texshop find gnuplot in `/opt/local/bin`, because that version works manually. How could I do that?

Comment: I stumbled onto the same problem last year while trying to invoke gnuplot in TikZ, spending a whole night poking at the gnuplot installation via Terminal. Finally gave up when I realized I could also use the TikZ/PGF plot function to achieve similar results. Unfortunately, I don't think PGF has the gamma function defined. I may be wrong, though. There is some discussion about the issue on [texample.net](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/gnuplot-basics/). Placing `%& -shell-escape` or similar commands at the beginning of your document may work for you. Check out the comments.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they are [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "101010" on it).

Comment: @Jimi : it' interesting to use pgfmath but Gnuplot is faster and more accurate for drawing complicated functions. You can use gnuplot with pgfplots also.

Comment: The problem with `set terminal table` arrives only with an new version of gnuplot like 4.3 4.4 and perhaps 4.2 and pgf <= 2.0. the good way is to use gnuplot >= 4.3 and pgf 2.1. Pgf 2.1 and gnuplot 4.0 must make a problem

Comment: @Szabolcs Sebestyen :  pgfplot for complicated expressions has the possibility to use  gnuplot !

Comment: About 3. You have several version of gnuplot. First you need to know your PATH with `$echo $PATH` then you know to locate your versions of gnupplot. You need to delete 4.0 and you can replace it by a symbolic link through the 4.4 version.

Comment: About `--shell-escape`With texshop with pdflatex you need in the prefs add for the engines : `pdflatex --file-line-error --shell-escape --synctex=1`but for latex (dvi mode) it's `simpdftex latex --maxpfb --extratexopts "-file-line-error  -shell-escape -synctex=1"`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply.
How can I see the version of pgf? I think I have 2.1 as I frequently update the packages through Tex Live, but I'm not completely sure.
When I write `echo $PATH` into Terminal I get
`/sw/bin:/sw/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/texbin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin`
What does this mean? And how can I delete the older version?
Sorry for the stupid questions, but I'm everything but familiar with installation and configuration via Terminal.

Comment: @Szabolcs: The answer section is only for solutions. Please edit your original question if you want to provide more information. You can post your final solution as self-answer if you want. Please also register your account here. At the moment you generate a new, different unregistered account every time you post. I merged these accounts now together.

Comment: @Martin Scharrer: Thanks a lot for your help in editing and sorry for the confusion, but it's the first time I write here.

Comment: @Szabolcs:  You can execute files from folders like /bin or /usr/bin or usr/local/bin. The order of the folders are important. If gnuplot is inside /sw/bin and /usr/local/bin The first one will be executed. You installed Fink (sw) and Macport(opt) perhaps you have three version of gnuplot. This is the main reason I don't like very much Fink and Macport. If you want to remove something from `/usr/local/bin` you can make `$cd /usr/local/bin`then `$sudo rm gnuplot`

Comment: @Szabolcs Sebestyen: No problem. You are welcome.

Comment: This isn't a direct answer to your question, however, my preferred way for converting Gnuplot figures for use in LaTeX documents is by exporting as an XFig figure and converting to TikZ, as I described [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7116/use-unicode-font-for-cyrillic-in-gnuplot#7125).

Answer (score 4):

1. First you need to test if `gnuplot` works. I compiled the source but you can work with a fink or macport version;
2. Now you can test `gnuplot` in the terminal `$ gnuplot`;
3. Then `gnuplot` must be find in the `path`. A simple solution is to create a link for example in `/usr/local/bin/` through the real  file `gnuplot` but if you know how do you can modifify your path directly (to test the path in the terminal :`$ echo $PATH`)
4. And finally, you need to authorize `TeX`to launch 'gnuplot`with`--shell-escape`in your script for the compilation.

I don't like very much the use of Fink or Macport and I prefer to compile the sources. By default the binary will be inside /usr/local/bin ( I think ..) but it's easy to change. The next method is only to get a version to use with tikz and to get a table. It's more complicate to get a version with all terminals (png, etc.)
A good thing is to install Aquaterm !

1. Download the sources from : [gnuplot sources](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuplot/files/gnuplot/4.4.3/gnuplot-4.4.3.tar.gz/download) then put the folder gnuplot-4.4.3 on your desktop
2. `$ cd /Users/.../Desktop/gnuplot-4.4.3`
3. `$ ./configure --with-readline=builtin` to avoid a problem with a bad readline on Leopard.
4. `$ make`
5. `$ sudo make install`
6. test of gnuplot `$ gnuplot`
7. make a try with TexShop, this is the easiest way to work with TeX.

Comment: I tried manual compilation once and it took hours...

Comment: Hours ??? it's long but only if you install  a lot of librairies to work with all kinds of terminals. I know that is  boring but I'm not a unix expert and I installed gnuplot several times .