# A problem with "Tikz + Gnuplot", set terminal table

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, gnuplot

When I use Tikz to plot a function. I followed the instruction to use gnuplot to do so. I did that half year before. But now when I recompile, the gnuplot has problem with the first line of its generated .gnuplot file:

```
set terminal table
```

Does anyone know the problem? My gnuplot version is 4.4 patchlevel 2. Do I need to use an older version?

Thank you very much!

EDIT: my file is here:

A minimal example

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{graphicx,url,psfrag}
\usepackage[noxcolor,usenames]{pstricks}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calc,decorations.fractals,through}
\usepgflibrary{plotmarks}
\usepackage{pgfmath}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,amscd}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\def\tI{1}
\def\xI{3}
\def\tII{2}
\def\xII{1}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7,domain=\tII:5]

\draw[help lines,step=1] (0,-3) grid (5,5.5);
\draw [->] (-0.5,0) -- (0,0) coordinate [label=-135:$O$] (O) -- (6,0)
coordinate [label=right:$t$] (T);
\draw [->] (0,-3.2)  -- (0,6) coordinate [label=above:$x$] (X);

\draw [dashed,thick] (0,\xI) coordinate [label=left:$x_1$] -- (\tI,\xI) --
(\tI,0) coordinate [label=below:$t_1$] ;
\draw [dashed,thick] (0,\xII) coordinate [label=left:$x_2$] -- (\tII,\xII) --
(\tII,0) coordinate [label=below:$t_2$] ;

\foreach \r in {-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3}
{
\draw plot [id=HeatSample-\r]
function{
((x-\tI)*\xII+(x-\tII)*\xI)/(2*x-\tI-\tII)+sqrt((x-\tI)*(x-\tII)/(2*x-\tI-\tII)
) * \r} node [right] {$\r$};
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Even with the basic examples in http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/gnuplot/, my system has problems with

```
set terminal table;
```

I think it is the problem of my gnuplot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following up on Thorsten's answer, a work around is to explicitly change this in the pgf file that calls gnuplot.  For my texlive installation, the file I had to change is:

```
/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfbaseplot.code.tex
```

Change this line:

```
\xdef\pgf@gnuplot@head#1{set terminal table; set output "#1.table"; set format "%.5f"}
```

to this:

```
\xdef\pgf@gnuplot@head#1{set table; set output "#1.table"; set format "%.5f"}
```

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that you have Version 2.10 of [pgf/tikZ](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf) installed to make it work with current versions of Gnuplot. In these versions (I guess since 4.4.0) the setting of the »table« terminal in Gnuplot has changed from `set terminal table` to `set table`. Actually there should be some information about that in the log file.

Comment: Yes, It is. Now it works. Thanks a lot! :-)

Answer (score 1):

After reading the post: [TikZ + gnuplot on a Mac](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14847/tikz-gnuplot-on-a-mac)

I change the line

```
\xdef\pgf@gnuplot@head#1{set terminal table; set output “#1.table”; set format “%.5f”}
```

to

```
\xdef\pgf@gnuplot@head#1{set table; set output “#1.table”; set format “%.5f”}
```

in the file `/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.tex`.

Then it works well again.

Thanks Thorsten!

Comment: Why don't you just update the [pgf/tikZ](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf) package?